# use PHP to unpack, process and pack array

Tags: php, arrays, pack

I read bytes from a file and process them. Afterwards I would like to save the packed bytes.

What is the recommended+generic way to convert an array with mixed objects/types to a byte string? In my case: array with int and string, pack types a,C,x.

A simplified example:

```
// $bytes = fread($handle, 100);
$bytes = "437XYZ25.011001DBEFORE                          ....";

$unpackString = "a3CPN/x8spare/CDSC/x4spare/a32OPT";
$unpacked = unpack($unpackString, $bytes);

var_dump($unpacked);
/*
array(3) {
  ["CPN"]=> string(3) "437"
  ["DSC"]=> int(49)
  ["OPT"]=> string(32) "BEFORE                          "
}
*/

// example of processing
$unpacked["DSC"] = 12;
$unpacked["OPT"] = "AFTER                           ";

// pack + write the result
// $packString = "a3x8Cx4a32";
$packTypes = ["a3","x8","C","x4","a32"];
$packFields = [ $unpacked["CPN"], null, $unpacked["DSC"], null, $unpacked["OPT"] ];
// ...
```

**update**: in the simplified example I have replaced `$packString` with `$packTypes` and `$packFields` to make sure it is clear what content belongs where and with what type.

Comment: What's the question? You use `unpack` to unpack the array, why can't you use `pack` to pack it again? Is the problem with the fact that `pack` accepts arguments instead of a single array?

Comment: Indeed. How to pack using the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose what you're looking for is a way to call `pack`, which accepts arguments with an associative array as you have in your example. For this, we can use `call_user_func_array` which calls a function by its name and provides its arguments from a given array.

```
$bytes = "437XYZ25.011001DBEFORE                          ....";
$unpackString = "a3CPN/x8spare/CDSC/x4spare/a32OPT";
$unpacked = unpack($unpackString, $bytes);

// example of processing
$unpacked["DSC"] = 12;
$unpacked["OPT"] = "AFTER                           ";

// pack + write the result
$packTypes = ["a3", "x8", "C", "x4", "a32"];
$packFields = [$unpacked["CPN"], null, $unpacked["DSC"], null, $unpacked["OPT"]];

$packString = "";
$packArguments = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($packTypes); $i++){
    $packString .= $packTypes[$i];
    if ($packFields[$i] !== null){
        // the null bytes don't use an argument
        $packArguments[] = $packFields[$i];
    }
}

// put packString as the first argument
array_unshift($packArguments, $packString);

$output = call_user_func_array("pack", $packArguments);
```

And `$output` would then be:

```
00000000  34 33 37 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 0c 00 00 00 00  |437.............|
00000010  41 46 54 45 52 20 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |AFTER           |
00000020  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |                |
00000030
```

Comment: Wonderful. I saw the call_user_func_array approach before but was missing the context. Thanks!